# Special order filter (by language) in CP for Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, control-panel, order

We have a online-shop for german customers (Craft 2 + Commerce 1) and will expand the shop for american customers (via second domain).
Is there a way to filter the order (status) views in the Backend by domain/language.
The purpose is that the american backend user should only see orders that come via the american domain and the german backend user should see only german based orders.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with the system by default. Commerce doesn't support multi-store yet (and wont in Commerce 1).

If you want, a plugin could modify the order sources on the left side of the order listing screen using the hook:

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/hooks-reference#commerce_modifyordersources

In this hook you could show/hide sources depending on the user, and add sources for filtering my orderLanguage etc.

Comment: We will update to Commerce 2 anyway. Technicaly this should be no multishop (same invoice number circle for all customers). But if i can filter the order sources that may help.